# Passing javascript variable from iframe to URL

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

Lets say I have a function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ReturnURL()
{
var url = document.URL;
var url2 = url.split("=");
var urlID = url2[url2.length-1];


//window.open('http://localhost/POSkill/skillshow.aspx?user_id =' + urlID);
return urlID;
}

</script>
```

And I also have iframe in my html file which is something like below:

```
<iframe id="showSkill" scrolling="yes" src="http://localhost/POSkill/skillshow.aspx?user_id = ReturnURL()" height="350" runat="server" ></iframe>
```

Now all I want to do is to send the **urlID** value of **javasrcipt** as the **user_id** value in iframe. I have tried by using **user_id = ReturnURL()** but its not working.

How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I answered something very similar at [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693612/javascript-output-to-url/8693638#8693638)

The answer is that you must set the "src" value on the JS rendering.

This means that somewhere in your javascript you should have the following code

```
...
document.getElementById("showSkill").src="http://localhost/POSkill/skillshow.aspx?user_id =" +  ReturnURL()
...
```

This should work just fine.